# Facebook share link has a plain white image thumbnail

Tags: links, facebook, meta-tags

When I try to share my self-hosted website (www.veffa.org/vnbookdrive) on Facebook, the logo isn't shown as I expect:

[image: image description]

When search for the solution, I come up with [this tutorial in YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2pSRx2f7Bc). So I go to the [Facebook Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.veffa.org%2Fvnbookdrive) and enter my site. It turns out that it does get an image, the only thing is that image is white, and I don't know where it is on my site:

[image: image description]

So do you have any idea where is this image? And how should I fix it?

Comment: I have same problem. It worked a week ago. OG image is correct, image url is correct, if i inspect element on facebook on my post on image, the url of image is correct. and it still show white image. if i go to Open Graph Object Debugger i get "Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped." on any url of the website.... anyone any ideas?

Comment: @ErikKubica  that sounds like a separate issue since you have an error message.   You could ask a question about that error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are using Jetpack Open Graph Tags which is inserting the following code: `<meta property="og:image" content="https://s0.wp.com/i/blank.jpg" />`. It may be using a blank.jpg file because it can't find any images on the page. The only images you are using are contained within a JavaScript Super Sized...

Summary... either embed a image to the page not using JavaScript or manually add a og:image with a image that isn't blank.

Comment: My image I want to use is the logo, which doesn't seem to be contained in any JS

Comment: Right... Facebook uses `og:image` if you don't that in the `<head>` then its not going to display. I see that you have `<img src="/vnbookdrive/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/3.44.png>` on the page and you need to add `<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.veffa.org/vnbookdrive/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/3.44.png" />` to your website. Either do this manually, fix Jetpack Open Graph or use another plugin... I have told you the problem, how you proceed to fix the problem is up to you.

Comment: Thanks. I find [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-meta-tags/screenshots/) works